# Algebra on ODE hides some of the graph behavior

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to describe the behavior of $p' = 3p - 2p^2$. (From Nagles, Saff, Snider: *Fundamentals of Differential Equations* 9th Ed. Ch.1.3 Problem 5.)

My issue: I would expect that integrating $p(t)$ (result shown below) would give an equation that fully describes the behavior. However, the direction field makes it clear there's another important feature. I'm surprised that integration is "hiding" information from me, namely that if $p(0) = 0$, then $p$ should just stay at zero.

To solve, I separated $p'$ then used partial fractions to get:

$p(t) = \frac{3}{Ce^{-3t} + 2}$

This tells me that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}p(x)\to 3/2$. Here's $p(t)$ graphed using $C=\pm 1$: [image: p(t) for different Cs]

Notice that the initial condition of $p(0) = 0$ isn't even possible.

Compare this with the direction field: [image: direction field]

Solution C stays at $p=0$. Is this not a valid solution because $p(t)$ doesn't allow a value like $p(0)=0$? How can I tell from the equations that there's this sort of ultra-sensitive island of stability at p = 0?

Comment: Always look for the constant solutions first. These are $p=0$ and $p = 3/2,$ because then $3p-2p^2 = 0$

Comment: Yes, the first thing I did was find where $p'$ is constant as you suggested. Then when I went to algebraically manipulate things (for the sake of curiosity), I couldn't find that $p=0$ term. On the contrary, the $p(t)$ equation I have doesn't allow $p=0$ afaik.

Comment: If you look more carefully at your partial fraction process, you should find that the assumptions $p \neq 0$ and $p \neq 3/2$ are built in, necessary for performing the calculation at all. You begin, after all, with $$ \frac{p'}{3p-2p^2} = 1 $$

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. But can I integrate without those assumptions? And also in the final solution, it seems $p=3/2$ escapes that assumption as the graph tends toward $p=3/2$. It's curious how one assumption escapes and the other doesn't.

Comment: Look more carefully... Solutions do approach 3/2 at $t \rightarrow \infty^+.$ This rules out the solutions less than $0$ as those blow up in finite time. Solutions do approach $0$ at $t \rightarrow \infty^-.$ This rules out the solutions greater than $3/2$ as those blow up in finite backwards time.

Comment: I see that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty^+}p\to 3/2$ and backwards in time $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty^-}p\to 0$, however the mystery for me was that I couldn't understand where the island of stability starting at $p(0)=0$ came from moving fowards in time. But I see now that reparametrizing $C$ in terms of $p_0$ clears it up! Thank you for the help, especially with the reminder that I need to be mindful of what I'm doing when I use partial fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express the constant $C$ in the initial value $p(0)=p_0$ and simplify the resulting expression for the solution.
$$
p_0=\frac{3}{2+C}\iff C=\frac{3}{p_0}-2
$$
then
$$
p(t)=\frac{3}{2+(\frac{3}{p_0}-2)e^{-3t}}=\frac{3p_0}{2p_0+(3-2p_0)e^{-3t}}
$$
and this last expression also parametrizes the constant solutions correctly.

Comment: Your answer also cleared up a question I wasn't fully aware I had: What is the relationship between $C$ and $p_0$? Now I see how they're connected. Thanks for the twofer!